# Multiple properties in ReactJS inlined styles object?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How do I write something that is equivalent to

**CSS**

```
.class {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

but using inline styles in React?

I'm basically looking for something like:

**JavaScript**

```
let styles = {
  display: ['flex', '-webkit-flex']
}
```

Comment: This one have lot of options. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a [reactJS common problem still opened](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2020) and waiting for a proper solution

For webkit style, one solution is to concat values:

```
let styles = {
  display: 'flex; display:-webkit-flex'
}
```

Otherwise, a more common solution is to create a CSS named '`flex`' that will be given to the `className` property of your element.

Third solution: use [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium). I believe it too big & tedious for your problem but you can try it if you have time... :)